# exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Please help `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` is throwing this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

How can I solve this?

Code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     int o;

     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;Initial Catalog=FamilyDatabase;Integrated Security=True");
     con.Open();

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Family values('" + NameTextBox.Text + "', '" + SonTextBox.Text + "', '" + AddressTextBox.Text + "', " + NICTextBox.Text + ", " + BirthTextBox.Text + ", " + ExpiryTextBox.Text + ", " + IssueTextBox.Text + ", '" + FamilyNoTextBox.Text + "');", con);

     o = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     MessageBox.Show(o + " :Record has been inserted");
     con.Close();
}
```

Comment: please use PreparedStatement for your sql. Furthermore try to remove the semicolon at the end of your sql.

Comment: I use the preparedStatement but the problem is still their.

Comment: whenever i click on submit button it gives an unhandled exception error on cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Does the exception has an inner exception?

Comment: No can you tell how to add it?

Comment: Use sql parameters on your command object.

Comment: in addition to the already mentioned things i suggest to specify the column list in the insert statement to ensure that the values are assigned to the correct column ... and you could catch the SqlException and display the contained Message ...